# Skateboard model clean layer cuts

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpt

I'm struggling a lot with this skateboard that I want to cut in layers (and still have the shape of the skate mold for every layers..)

I need to cut this in 7 different parts just like the example below (and animate the layers separating themselves).

Does someone have any idea of the technique I should use to make the cuts as clean as possible?

Thanks a lot guys!
[image: Skate Layer example]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe flatten the shape and duplicate it? Also, why do you need such a high-poly mesh? Maybe simplify and give it a Subdivision Surface modifier?